# Can I use Python in Eclipse to develop Google Cloud Data Flow jobs

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

I've tried to run the `HelloWorld` example from the [get started guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK/blob/master/README.md) in an eclipse python project but get errors.

Should I be able to do this or can I only use the virtual environment at the moment?

Mez63

Answer (score 1):

Short answer -- we did not spend time on the Eclipse developer scenario. Probably better to stick to virtual environments unless you know well how to configure Eclipse.